# JQuery UI slider error (TypeError: max.toFixed is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

There is a Jquery UI double range slider on my website. But I'm getting the slider's max and min values from my database.

```
  $.ajax({
          url: "init.php",
          type: "GET",
          data : {"method": "price"},
          async: false,
          success: function(data){
          var result = JSON.parse(data);
          price.min = result.min;
          price.max = result.max;
          }
        });
```

So i have a

```
price = {
max: 0,
min: 1000
};
```

object and i give the new values values to the parameters in the ajax success function above.

---

```
 $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: price.min, //these don't work
            max: price.max,
            values: [ price.min, price.max ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " Ft" + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] + " Ft" );

            },
            change: function( event, ui){
              var values ={
                min: ui.values[0],
                max: ui.values[1]
              };
              filter("price",values);
            }
          });
          $( "#amount" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 )
            + " Ft" + " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )+ " Ft");
```

Here is my JQuery UI double range slider object
And I've got this error message in the console of the browser:

**TypeError: max.toFixed is not a function[Learn More]  jquery-ui.js:15006:26**

Comment: And how do you return those values from the ajax call ?

Comment: price.min = result.min;
 price.max = result.max;

Comment: this is in the success function

Comment: That's great, but the ajax call is **asynchronous**, how do you get those values into the slider ?

Comment: async: false, so this call is not asynchronous

Comment: The price object gets the values, i checked

Comment: `async : false` is deprecated in modern browsers, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: okay, but then how could i return those values?

Comment: If you just replace `price.max` and `price.min` with random numbers, does it work then ?

Comment: yes, then it works

Comment: So those values clearly aren't what you think they are.

Comment: You'd have to put the entire code that initializes the slider inside the success callback, or at least that's what you should be doing instead of trying to make ajax synchronous.

Comment: Even though the resultset seems to be integer, I have a feeling that result is not a json object. so it seems like price.max is not a numeric value that doesn't have toFixed() prototype function. try parseInt(result.max,10);

Comment: ^ that, passing strings is also not allowed -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/u3hqf5sv/

Comment: @serdar.sanri it is a json object and those are numeric values https://ibb.co/cZhnEk

Comment: well, then easiest way to find out is put a break-point at that line in jquery-ui.js file and see what does `max` gets as value. most likely it's either null or undefined.

Comment: It gets the correct min value and a random high max value https://ibb.co/kGwa0Q

Comment: And if you do `console.log( typeof price.max )` does it say "number"

Comment: No, it says string

Comment: I converted it to number and now it works, thanks @adeneo

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution:

```
min: Number(price.min),
max: Number(price.max),
```

thanks @adeneo